# Using the inline '--command' argument with psql doesn't produce logs in .psql_history

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

When I log into my PostgreSQL server manually on Ubuntu and execute a command, I can then find it logged in `/root/.psql_history`.

However when I try to run a command in a bash script via `psql -c "*query goes here*"`, the command returns data but is not logged in `.psql_history`.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command line retrieval and editing, as well as the history file, are functions of the “readline” library that is linked to `psql`.

Readline support is only active in interactive sessions, so there is also no history written if you invoke `psql` with the `-c` or `-f` options.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. Do you know of any other way to run a PostgreSQL query from a bash script and successfully have it logged in .psql_history?

Comment: No, I cannot think of a way to do that. But if you tell me what the ultimate goal is, maybe there are other ways to achieve them.